# No Repeated Primary Key

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
protected void btn_Insert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int result = 0;      

    storageprice sp = new storageprice(tb_PriceID.Text, tb_StorageName.Text, tb_Desc.Text, decimal.Parse(tb_StorePrice.Text), int.Parse(tb_OutletID.Text));

    result = sp.StoragePricingInsert();

    if (result > 1)
    {
        Response.Write("<script>alert('Storage Remove Successfullly');</script>");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("<script>alert('Storage Removal not successfull');</script>");
    }        

    Response.Redirect("StoragePricingView.aspx");
}
```

C# file

```
public int StoragePricingInsert()
{
    int result = 0;

    string queryStr = "INSERT INTO StoragePricing(Pricing_Id, Name, Description, Pricing, Outlet_Id)"
            + "values (@Pricing_ID, @Name, @Description, @Pricing, @Outlet_Id)";

    try
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryStr, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pricing_Id", this.Pricing_Id);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", this.Name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", this.Description);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pricing", this.Pricing);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Outlet_Id", this.OutletId);

        conn.Open();
        result += cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // returns no. of rows affected. Must be >0
        conn.Close();

        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

How do I only insert 1 unique string into my primary key?

Let's say I put `"bt01"` if I add and press `"bt01"` it would prompt already in use.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why do you make `Pricing_Id` editable at all, or what is your primary key? Why don't you use an identity column as primary key, then the id will be created automatically. If it must have a `bt` at the beginning you can format it in your frontend, f.e. `this.IdLabel.Text = String.Format("bt{0}",Pricing_Id.ToString("D2"))`

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 1):

Depends. If you don't care what the ID value is, let the database handle it - it should automatically assign the value depending on how it's configured - use an identity column as the primary key and the value will be assigned for you.

If you want to assign the value programmatically, you'll need to have a method which finds the highest value integer in your database, increment it and assign the value to your new record. You need to place both that method and the save method into a singleton to make it thread safe so the same value can't be added twice.

You could also look at using a Guid as your primary key instead of an int.